# SPARQL query for all people for an institution on dbpedia

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia

I'm trying to extract alumni lists for universities using SPARQL.

I've identified the ontologies I need:

- http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/University
- http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/Person

I tried this query, which [you can examine here](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=%20SELECT%20%2a%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?University%20dbpedia2%3aalumni%20?Person%20.%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A):

```
 SELECT * WHERE {
  ?University dbpedia2:alumni ?Person .
  }
```

Which seemed to make sense, except this returns counts instead of people, as the ontology says the property contains.

I found [this query](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20%2a%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/University%3E%20?property%20?hasValue%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20UNION%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20?isValueOf%20?property%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/University%3E%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) somewhere which seemed to do a better job finding universities, but was very slow.

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  { <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/University> ?property ?hasValue }
  UNION
  { ?isValueOf ?property <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/University> }
}
```

I also tried going the other way, start with all people and look for their almae matres, [in this form](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=%20SELECT%20%2a%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?person%20dbpedia2%3aalmaMater%20?University%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A):

```
 SELECT * WHERE {
  ?person dbpedia2:almaMater ?University
  }
```

But this is much slower, possibly because searching through the people space is too laborious.  This does actually work, but it returns a different set of results in application---namely, all people with a listed alma mater, rather than all people listed by universities as alumni.  I'd prefer a syntax that gets me the alumni.

How can I phrase this to return all alumni listed for universities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance of DBpedia's SPARQL endpoint can be a bit unreliable at times. After all, it's  apublic service, and isn't intended for huge queries.  Nonetheless, I think you can get what you're looking for here without too much trouble.  First, you can check how many results there are with a query like this at the [public SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql):

```
select (count(*) as ?nResults) where {
 ?person dbpedia-owl:almaMater ?almaMater
}
```

[SPARQL results (64928)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20%28count%28%2a%29%20as%20?nResults%29%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20?person%20dbpedia-owl%3aalmaMater%20?almaMater%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Now, if you just want the big list, you'd get it like this.  The `order by` helps organize the results for easy consumption, but isn't technically necessary:

```
select ?almaMater ?person where {
 ?person dbpedia-owl:almaMater ?almaMater
}
order by ?almaMater ?person
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?almaMater%20?person%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20?person%20dbpedia-owl%3aalmaMater%20?almaMater%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aorder%20by%20?almaMater%20?person&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

If you need to place some additional restrictions on `?almaMater`, e.g., to ensure that it's a university, then you can add them to the query.  For instance:

```
select ?almaMater ?person where {
 ?person dbpedia-owl:almaMater ?almaMater .
 ?almaMater a dbpedia-owl:University .
}
order by ?almaMater ?person
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?almaMater%20?person%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20?person%20dbpedia-owl%3aalmaMater%20?almaMater%20.%0D%0A%20?almaMater%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3aUniversity%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aorder%20by%20?almaMater%20?person&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: That's cool and makes sense, but it seems that some things one can be an alumni of are not universities---such as high schools, or military academies; the almaMater property takes an educationalInstitution object.  Sorry, I'm kind of new to SPARQL, but how would I subset this in your form above to limit it to only valid ?University objects?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how you can restrict `?almaMater` to things that have the type `dbpedia-owl:University`.

Answer (score 2):

Your first query:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?University dbpedia2:alumni ?Person .
}
```

isn't just returning counts; it's returning both counts and individual alumni.  Apparently dbpedia's data here is poor quality and there are a number of triples misusing the `dbpedia2:alumni` relation.

You can filter out the counts by adding a second condition requiring that an entity satisfying `Person` be a member of the appropriate class:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?university dbpedia2:alumni ?person .
  ?person rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>
}
```

What you see running this is that there are very few individuals tagged as alumni; the data is surprisingly scant, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

In your last query, you are almost there. However, you are currently asking for *any* resource that can take the place of the `?University` variable. As you only want universities to take that place, you can use another triple to further restrict that variable:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
    ?University a dbpedia-owl:University.
    ?person dbpedia2:almaMater ?University.
}
```

This means that `?University` can only be an individual of class `dbpedia-owl:University` (where `dbpedia-owl` is mapped to `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/`).